What is the best way to set up a windows 10 VM with Hypervisor and Virtual Machine Platform enabled on Ubuntu?
I have a Ubuntu 24.04 LTS device. i want to install Windows 10 and enable Windows hypervisor platform / Hyper-V and virtual machine platform. What's the best solution for achieve this goal?
Note:
I do not want to set-up dual boot. It should be easy to use like virtualbox (turn on and off anytime when using ubuntu)
I do not have a problem about CPU or RAM capacity.
I expect good hardware performance in windows 10 virtual machine and no lags or graphical issues.
I do not need to know how to install windows 10 or enable windows hypervisor platform and virtual machine platform.
1 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/quick-start/enable-hyper-v#enable-the-hyper-v-role-through-settings
2 https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/enable-virtualization-on-windows-c5578302-6e43-4b4b-a449-8ced115f58e1
If anyone is curious why I want to do this:
(a) I want to enable and test Windows Subsystem for Android.
(If you want to use android apps on Linux. I recommend you to use https://waydro.id/. Alternatively, you can install (credit: @raj comment) Android x86, BlissOS or other on KVM, virtualbox or vmware.
(b) I want to use Onenote. I couldn't find a successful way to install it through Wine on Ubuntu. I also know https://snapcraft.io/onenote-desktop https://github.com/patrikx3/onenote but it is cloud based. I know other popular Onenote alternatives and I don't feel satisfied. So I am doing this as a 2-in-1 solution.

Is "Windows subsystem for Android" some kind of an Android emulator?
Can't you install just an Android virtual machine instead? There is a PC version of Android, even two I know about (Android x86 and BlissOS). Maybe it's worth to give it a try before attempting virtualization-within-virtualization?

To be clear you want to use kvm-virtualization/qemu to create a VM with Windows guest. Then you want to use hypervisor to create a VM inside the VM. It is like creating a Matrix inside The Matrix!

You may find this useful.

@user68186 Is it correct to follow this guide? https://phoenixnap.com/kb/ubuntu-install-kvm After following the above guide and creating a windows 10 VM, I hope there are no errors while enabling these https://i.ibb.co/xqMy8fp/windows-features.png

You have to try for yourself and find out. Update the question if you get any errors.

https://docs.oracle.com/en/virtualization/virtualbox/6.0/admin/nested-virt.html Did you try this?

@FedKad I'm using virtualbox 7.0.16 and guest os shows "a hypervisor has been detected. features required for hyper-v will not be displayed". If checked to enable the Hyper-V on windows features, a black box shows inside the checkbox and I already ignored it and enabled Hyper-V. After that the guest os got corrupted. I think this is a virtualbox bug? Please see the screenshots.  https://i.ibb.co/7Nd29nj/Screenshot-1.png, https://i.ibb.co/dKnsxLG/Screenshot-2.png, https://i.ibb.co/pKRHQ7k/Screenshot-3.png, https://i.ibb.co/XSCHRXX/Screenshot-4.png, https://i.ibb.co/qm2t7Fp/Screenshot-5.png

@FedKad It doesn't work and virtualbox developers haven't replied to this thread.
https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?p=496666#p496666
According to OP, hyper-v can be enabled in windows server 2016 guest.

See https://i.sstatic.net/fzSKzJt6.png. f someone has similar requirement, you can follow this guide to set-up KVM. This's the best solution i can recommend. https://phoenixnap.com/kb/ubuntu-install-kvm PS: When i have free time, I'll post an answer.

@minjs I would not be using Hyper-V if your host system isn't Windows.  Hyper-V doesn't like to behave when in a nested virtualization type setup

If someone has similar requirement, you can follow this simple guide to install KVM, Create Windows 10 / Windows 11 VM and set-up Windows Subsystem for Android. You can also install offline Onenote from MS store. This is the best solution i can recommend.

Please check if your CPU supports hardware virtualization and can use KVM acceleration. (If kvm-ok doesn't work, install cpu-checker package. sudo apt install cpu-checker)
egrep -c '(vmx|svm)' /proc/cpuinfo
sudo kvm-ok


Install KVM Packages and Virt Manager.
sudo apt install qemu-kvm libvirt-daemon-system libvirt-clients bridge-utils virt-manager


Members of the libvirt and kvm user groups can run virtual machines. If you want specific users to run VMs, add them to those user groups.
sudo adduser [username] libvirt
sudo adduser [username] kvm


Start virt manager and create VM. Launch!
sudo virt-manager











(You can choose resources as you need. If you allocate more resources, guest os will run smoothly)
Notes:
If you check the guest os systeminfo. you'll see "a hypervisor has been detected. features required for hyper-v will not be displayed". You can ignore it. Search for Turn Windows features on or off and enable Hyper-V, Virtual Machine Platform and Windows Hypervisor Platform. After that, you can set-up Windows subsystem for Android. "Microsoft is ending support for the Windows Subsystem for Android™️ (WSA). source. There're many linux solutions, you can try them.


